# I need to clear a date using a separate control; jquery datepicker is in effect

Tags: jquery, input, datepicker

I have a form with the following dynamically added row:

```
<input type="text" name="statuseffective" id="statuseffective_0" class="datepicker" size="15" sid="0" ordr="0">  
<span style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; margin-bottom:-14px;" onclick="clearDate();">Clear</span>
```

the name statuseffective with id of statuseffective_0 is a dynamically added row.  To keep cracker jacks from entering dates such as 01/01/1752 into my text box, I'm having to make the field readonly using `$('.datepicker').datepicker().attr("readOnly", true)` since they were ignoring the jquery popup calendar.  The default behaviour of datepicker still allows the user to key in dates using the keys - I need to prevent that.  since the keys are now disabled, I need a way to allow the user to clear out the dates so I'm adding a "clear" option after the text input field.  Since the rows can be dynamically added, how can I obtain the value of the input field just before the clear text?  The code shown in the beginning of this post is what I'm working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would take out the inline js and use [.live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

for the html

```
<input type="text" name="statuseffective" id="statuseffective_0" class="datepicker" size="15" sid="0" ordr="0">  
<span style="cursor:pointer; text-decoration:underline; margin-bottom:-14px;" class="clear">Clear</span>
```

then in your doc ready

```
$('.clear').live('click',function(){
        var before_val = $(this).prev().val();
        $(this).prev().val("")
});
```

Comment: ah, you remembered the dynamically added content.  .live was crucial here and when implemented, worked perfectly.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this instead of placing an onclick event in the markup of your span:

```
$('.datepicker').next('span').click(function() { $(this).prev().val(''); });
```

Comment: What an interesting approach... I have to go to lunch now but I'll check this out when I return... again, very interesting approach.

Comment: I went with mcgrailm approach because of the .live approach.  Since this is a dynamically added element, the .live accounts for dynamically added objects after the DOM has loaded.  Otherwise, I think your suggestion would have worked fine for static content.

Comment: @dlackey  Sorry, but I missed that part of your original question.  the other suggestion works for that, though you might want to look at .delegate() instead of .live()

Comment: not familiar with that tag but I will look into that, too.  Thanks.